# Converting DIV element into String

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div element that I want to be printed on the page when I click a Create Button.

Thus, when I click create I call a function that has: `document.getElementById("createdDiv").textContent = document.querySelector("[data-feed]");`

This finds my div element and prints to the page `[object HTMLDivElement]`

However, when I print the element to the console, I get my div element:

```
<div data-feed class="feed-element" ... ></div>
```

I know the console has a toString function that converts the div element into a string but I am not sure how to do this in javascript so I can print the same string to the page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `outerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("createdDiv").textContent = document.querySelector("[data-feed]").outerHTML;
```

```js
document.getElementById("createdDiv").textContent = document.querySelector("[data-feed]").outerHTML;
```

```css
[data-feed]::before {
  content: 'The source element: ';
  color: #f00;
}

#createdDiv {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div data-feed="something"><span>Text in here</span> with <em>various</em> <strong>elements</strong></div>
<div id="createdDiv"></div>
```

In order to remove HTML from any childNodes, then you could use a function to clone the node, remove the children, and then return only the `outerHTML` of that specific node:

```
function tagHTMLOnly(elem) {
  var temp = elem.cloneNode();
  while (temp.firstChild) {
    temp.removeChild(temp.firstChild);
  }
  return temp.outerHTML;
}

document.getElementById("createdDiv").textContent = tagHTMLOnly(document.querySelector("[data-feed]"));
```

```js
function tagHTMLOnly(elem) {
  var temp = elem.cloneNode();
  while (temp.firstChild) {
    temp.removeChild(temp.firstChild);
  }
  return temp.outerHTML;
}

document.getElementById("createdDiv").textContent = tagHTMLOnly(document.querySelector("[data-feed]"));
```

```css
[data-feed]::before {
  content: 'The source element: ';
  color: #f00;
}
#createdDiv {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div data-feed="something"><span>Text in here</span> with <em>various</em>  <strong>elements</strong>
</div>
<div id="createdDiv"></div>
```

References:

- [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML).

Comment: Is there a way for outerHTML to only select the parent Div tag? I do not want the descendants.

Comment: Do you know why I'm getting TypeError: Undefined is not a function for the line: var temp = elem.cloneNode();  ?

Comment: Offhand, no; it doesn't give errors for me. But are we discussing the *demo*, or *your implementation*?